# Is there a Julia function that converts bitstrings to Ints?

Tags: parsing, julia, deserialization

Evaluating

```
bitstring(Int8(3))
```

returns `"00000011"`. Is there an in-built function in Julia to do the inverse operation of parsing a bitstring to an integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `parse(::Type{T}, s::AbstractString; kwargs...)` takes `base` as one of the keyword arguments. See: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/539f3ce943f59dec8aff3f2238b083f1b27f41e5/base/parse.jl#L376 and https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/539f3ce943f59dec8aff3f2238b083f1b27f41e5/base/parse.jl#L92.

So, you can do:

```
parse(Int8, bitstring(Int8(3)), base=2)
```

and it correctly returns `3`.